# buffer não é limpo durante a segunda execução do cilclo

Tags: c

Durante a segunda execução do loop for o setbuf não surti efeito e caso o 2º 'produto' possuir mais de 14 characters atribuiu os demais caracteres para as proximas posições.

```
#include <stdio.h>

 const int MAX=5;
 const int QCH=15;

int main(){

char nomes[MAX][QCH];
int i;

for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
    printf("\nForneça o nome do %dº produto:",i+1);
    fgets(nomes[i],QCH,stdin);
    setbuf(stdin,NULL);
}


for (i=0;i<MAX;i++){
    printf("\n%s",nomes[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embora a definição não especifique `fflush` para uma *stream* de entrada como o *stdin*, alguns compiladores suportam isso, o que faz com o seu problema nesses casos possa ser resolvido trocando `setbuf(stdin,NULL);` por:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Outra alternativa, que segue a definição corretamente, é ler o que falta até ao final da linha, se o que foi lido ultrapassar o limite indicado no `fgets`. Para perceber se leu até ao final da linha pode achar o `\n` na linha utilizando a função [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/), que lhe vai devolver `NULL` caso não exista, ou um ponteiro válido caso exista.

Implementação:

```
for(i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
    printf("\nForneça o nome do %dº produto:",i+1);
    fgets(nomes[i],QCH,stdin);

    if(!strchr(nomes[i], '\n')){ //se o nome não tem \n então ultrapassou o limite 
        scanf("%*[^\n]"); //lê até ao final da linha
        scanf("%*c"); //lê a quebra de linha
    }
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/xoVdvr)

Repare que as leituras no `scanf` foram feitas com `*` pois o que é lido é para ser descartado, e assim evita ter de criar uma variável apenas para ler o que sobrou.

---

A função `setbuf` indica se as leituras e ou escritas são bufferizadas, o que implica que possam não ser feitas no momento que as chama. Isto no entanto não está relacionado com descartar o que ficou a mais na stream de entrada.